# Ubuntu does not recognize Kali tools

Tags: kali-linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install all Kali tools to my Ubuntu 21.10:

```
sudo apt install 0trace abootimg aesfix aeskeyfind afflib-tools afl++ aircrack-ng airgeddon altdns amap amass android-sdk apache-users apache2 apktool arjun armitage arp-scan arping arpwatch asleap assetfinder atftp autopsy axel backdoor-factory bed beef-xss berate-ap bettercap bind9 bing-ip2hosts binwalk bloodhound bluelog blueranger bluesnarfer bluetooth braa bruteforce-salted-openssl bruteforce-wallet brutespray btscanner bulk-extractor bully burpsuite bytecode-viewer cabextract cadaver caldera capstone-tool ccrypt certgraph cewl changeme chaosreader cherrytree chirp chisel chkrootkit chntpw chromium cisco-auditing-tool cisco-global-exploiter cisco-ocs cisco-torch cloud-enum cloudbrute cmospwd cmseek code-oss command-not-found commix copy-router-config covenant-kbx cowpatty crack crackle crackmapexec creddump7 crowbar crunch cryptcat cryptsetup cryptsetup-nuke-password curlftpfs cutecom cutycapt cymothoa darkstat davtest dbd dbeaver dc3dd dcfldd ddrescue de4dot dex2jar python3-dfdatetime python3-dfvfs python3-dfwinreg dhcpig dirb dirbuster dirsearch dsniff dislocker libdistorm3-3 dmitry dns2tcp dnscat2 dnschef dnsenum dnsgen dnsmap dnsrecon dnstracer dnstwist dnswalk doona dos2unix dotdotpwn dradis driftnet dumpsterdiver dumpzilla eaphammer eapmd5pass edb-debugger emailharvester enum4linux enumiax ethtool ettercap-common evil-ssdp exe2hexbat exifprobe exiv2 expect exploitdb exploitdb-bin-sploits exploitdb-papers ext3grep ext4magic extundelete eyewitness fake-hwclock fcrackzip fern-wifi-cracker feroxbuster ffuf fierce fiked finalrecon firefox-developer-edition-en-us-kbx firewalk firmware-mod-kit firmware-sof-signed flashrom foremost forensic-artifacts forensics-colorize fping fragrouter framework2 freeradius freeradius-wpe freerdp2-dev ftester galleta gdb getallurls ghidra gitleaks gnuradio gobuster godoh golang-github-binject-go-donut goldeneye goofile gospider gpart gparted gpp-decrypt gqrx-sdr gr-air-modes gr-iqbal gr-osmosdr grokevt gss-ntlmssp guymager gvm hackrf hamster-sidejack hash-identifier hashcat hashcat-utils hashdeep hashid hashrat hb-honeypot hcxtools heartleech hexinject libhivex-bin hostapd-mana hostapd-wpe hosthunter hotpatch hping3 htshells httprint httprobe httrack hurl hydra hyperion i2c-tools iaxflood ibombshell ident-user-enum ifenslave ike-scan python3-impacket impacket-scripts inetsim initramfs-tools inspectrum inspy instaloader intrace inviteflood iodine ipv6-toolkit irpas ismtp isr-evilgrade ivre iwjadx javasnoop jboss-autopwn jd-gui john johnny joomscan joplin jsql-injection kali-community-wallpapers kali-defaults kali-tweaks kali-legacy-wallpapers kalibrate-rtl king-phisher kismet knocker koadic laudanum lbd legion ewf-tools libfindrtp libfreefare-bin libnfc-bin libpst-dev linux-exploit-suggester clang dmeventd lynis mac-robber macchanger magicrescue maltego maltego-teeth maskprocessor masscan massdns mc libmdb3 mdk3 mdk4 medusa memdump mercurial metacam metagoofil metasploit-framework mfcuk mfoc mfterm mimikatz minicom miredo missidentify mitmproxy msfpc multimac multimon-ng myrescue default-libmysqlclient-dev nasm nasty nbtscan nbtscan-unixwiz ncat ncat-w32 ncrack ncurses-hexedit nmap nmapsi4 libnetsnmptrapd40 netbase netcat-traditional netdiscover ftp telnet tftp netmask netsed netsniff-ng netwag nextnet nfs-common ngrep nikto nipper-ng nishang o-saft oclgausscrack odat offsec-awae ohrwurm ollydbg onesixtyone openocd openssh-client ophcrack oscanner osrframework outguess owasp-mantra-ff owl p0f p7zip-full pack pacu padbuster paros parsero libparted-dev pasco passing-the-hash patator payloadsallthethings pdf-parser pdfcrack pdfid peirates perl-cisco-copyconfig pev phishery photon phishery libapache2-mod-php phpggc pipal pixiewps plaso plecost mlocate placate pnscan polenum pompem powercat powershell powershell-empire powersploit princeprocessor protos-sip libproxychains4 proxytunnel pskracker ptunnel pwnat pwncat faraday qemu qsslcaudit quark-engine libradare2-5.0.0 quark-engine radare2-cutter rainbowcrack rake rarcrack rcracki-mt rdesktop reaver rebind recon-ng recordmydesktop recoverdm recoverjpeg redfang redsnarf redsocks libregfi-dev regripper rephrase responder rfcat rfdump ridenum rifiuti rifiuti2 rkhunter golang-github-temoto-robotstxt-dev robotstxt ropper routerkeygenpc routersploit rsakeyfind rsmangler rtlsdr-scanner rtpbreak rtpflood rtpinsertsound rtpmixsound safecopy sakis3g ctdb samdump2 sbd scalpel python3-scapy screen scrounge-ntfs sctpscan seclists secure-socket-funneling-windows-binaries sendemail set sfuzz shed shellnoob shellter sherlock sidguesser siege silenttrinity siparmyknife sipcrack sipp sipsak sipvicious skipfish libtsk-dev sliver slowhttptest smali smbmap smtp-user-enum sniffjoke snmpcheck snmpenum snowdrop socat spectools spiderfoot spike spooftooph spraykatz sqldict sqlitebrowser sqlmap sqlninja sqlsus libfuzzy-dev ssldump sslh sslscan sslsniff sslsplit sslyze starkiller statsprocessor stegcracker steghide stegsnow stunnel4 subfinder subjack sublist3r libapache2-mod-svn sucrack swaks t50 tcpdump tcpflow tcpick tcpreplay teamsploit termineter testdisk testssl.sh tftpd32 thc-ipv6 thc-pptp-bruter thc-ssl-dos theharvester tightvncpasswd tlssled tmux tnftp tnscmd10g traceroute truecrack tundeep twofi u-boot u-boot-qemu u-boot-tools libubertooth-dev udptunnel libuhd-dev uhd-images undbx unhide unhide.rb unicornscan uniscan unix-privesc-check libunrar-dev libunrar-headers libunrar5 unrar upx-ucl urlcrazy usbutils bsdextrautils cgpt veil vim vinetto vlan voiphopper vpnc wafw00f wapiti watobo wce webacoo webscarab webshells websploit weevely wfuzz wgetpaste whatweb whois wifi-honey wifiphisher wifite wig wig-ng windows-binaries windows-privesc-check winexe winregfs libwireshark-data libwireshark-dev libwireshark15 wordlistraider wordlists wotmate wpa-sycophant wpscan xmount xplico xprobe xspy xsser libyara-dev yersinia zaproxy zenmap-kbx zerofree zim golang-github-zonedb-zonedb-dev zonedb zsh zsh-autosuggestions zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting -y
```

But this is my output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package u-boot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However, the following packages replace it:
  u-boot-tools u-boot-qemu

Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However, the following packages replace it:
  chromium-bsu

Package radare2-cutter is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package spike is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source


No apt package "amass", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install amass"


No apt package "feroxbuster", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install feroxbuster"


No apt package "joplin", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install joplin"


No apt package "powershell", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install powershell"


No apt package "zaproxy", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install zaproxy"

E: Unable to locate package 0trace
E: Unable to locate package airgeddon
E: Unable to locate package altdns
E: Unable to locate package amap
E: Unable to locate package amass
E: Unable to locate package apache-users
E: Unable to locate package arjun
E: Unable to locate package armitage
E: Unable to locate package asleap
E: Unable to locate package assetfinder
E: Unable to locate package bed
E: Unable to locate package beef-xss
E: Unable to locate package berate-ap
E: Unable to locate package bettercap
E: Unable to locate package bing-ip2hosts
E: Unable to locate package bloodhound
E: Unable to locate package bluelog
E: Unable to locate package blueranger
E: Unable to locate package bluesnarfer
E: Unable to locate package bulk-extractor
E: Unable to locate package burpsuite
E: Unable to locate package bytecode-viewer
E: Unable to locate package caldera
E: Unable to locate package certgraph
E: Unable to locate package chisel
E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package cisco-auditing-tool
E: Unable to locate package cisco-global-exploiter
E: Unable to locate package cisco-ocs
E: Unable to locate package cisco-torch
E: Unable to locate package cloud-enum
E: Unable to locate package cloudbrute
E: Unable to locate package cmseek
E: Unable to locate package code-oss
E: Unable to locate package commix
E: Unable to locate package copy-router-config
E: Unable to locate package covenant-kbx
E: Unable to locate package crackle
E: Unable to locate package crackmapexec
E: Unable to locate package creddump7
E: Unable to locate package crowbar
E: Unable to locate package cryptsetup-nuke-password
E: Unable to locate package cymothoa
E: Unable to locate package davtest
E: Unable to locate package dbd
E: Unable to locate package dbeaver
E: Unable to locate package ddrescue
E: Unable to locate package dex2jar
E: Unable to locate package dirbuster
E: Unable to locate package dirsearch
E: Unable to locate package dnscat2
E: Unable to locate package dnschef
E: Unable to locate package dnsgen
E: Unable to locate package dotdotpwn
E: Unable to locate package dradis
E: Unable to locate package dumpsterdiver
E: Unable to locate package dumpzilla
E: Unable to locate package eaphammer
E: Unable to locate package eapmd5pass
E: Unable to locate package emailharvester
E: Unable to locate package enum4linux
E: Unable to locate package enumiax
E: Unable to locate package evil-ssdp
E: Unable to locate package exe2hexbat
E: Unable to locate package exploitdb
E: Unable to locate package exploitdb-bin-sploits
E: Unable to locate package exploitdb-papers
E: Unable to locate package eyewitness
E: Unable to locate package fern-wifi-cracker
E: Unable to locate package feroxbuster
E: Unable to locate package fiked
E: Unable to locate package finalrecon
E: Unable to locate package firefox-developer-edition-en-us-kbx
E: Unable to locate package firewalk
E: Unable to locate package firmware-mod-kit
E: Unable to locate package fragrouter
E: Unable to locate package framework2
E: Unable to locate package freeradius-wpe
E: Unable to locate package ftester
E: Unable to locate package getallurls
E: Unable to locate package ghidra
E: Unable to locate package gitleaks
E: Unable to locate package godoh
E: Unable to locate package golang-github-binject-go-donut
E: Unable to locate package goofile
E: Unable to locate package gospider
E: Unable to locate package gpp-decrypt
E: Unable to locate package hamster-sidejack
E: Unable to locate package hash-identifier
E: Unable to locate package hashcat-utils
E: Unable to locate package hb-honeypot
E: Unable to locate package heartleech
E: Unable to locate package hexinject
E: Unable to locate package hostapd-mana
E: Unable to locate package hostapd-wpe
E: Unable to locate package hosthunter
E: Unable to locate package hotpatch
E: Unable to locate package htshells
E: Unable to locate package httprint
E: Unable to locate package httprobe
E: Unable to locate package hurl
E: Unable to locate package hyperion
E: Unable to locate package iaxflood
E: Unable to locate package ibombshell
E: Unable to locate package ident-user-enum
E: Unable to locate package impacket-scripts
E: Unable to locate package inspy
E: Unable to locate package instaloader
E: Unable to locate package intrace
E: Unable to locate package inviteflood
E: Unable to locate package ipv6-toolkit
E: Unable to locate package ismtp
E: Unable to locate package isr-evilgrade
E: Unable to locate package ivre
E: Unable to locate package iwjadx
E: Unable to locate package javasnoop
E: Unable to locate package jboss-autopwn
E: Unable to locate package jd-gui
E: Unable to locate package johnny
E: Unable to locate package joomscan
E: Unable to locate package joplin
E: Unable to locate package jsql-injection
E: Unable to locate package kali-community-wallpapers
E: Unable to locate package kali-defaults
E: Unable to locate package kali-tweaks
E: Unable to locate package kali-legacy-wallpapers
E: Unable to locate package kalibrate-rtl
E: Unable to locate package king-phisher
E: Unable to locate package kismet
E: Unable to locate package knocker
E: Unable to locate package koadic
E: Unable to locate package laudanum
E: Unable to locate package lbd
E: Unable to locate package legion
E: Unable to locate package libfindrtp
E: Unable to locate package linux-exploit-suggester
E: Unable to locate package maltego
E: Unable to locate package maltego-teeth
E: Unable to locate package massdns
E: Unable to locate package metagoofil
E: Unable to locate package metasploit-framework
E: Unable to locate package mfterm
E: Unable to locate package mimikatz
E: Unable to locate package msfpc
E: Unable to locate package multimac
E: Unable to locate package nbtscan-unixwiz
E: Unable to locate package ncat-w32
E: Unable to locate package nextnet
E: Unable to locate package nipper-ng
E: Unable to locate package nishang
E: Unable to locate package oclgausscrack
E: Unable to locate package odat
E: Unable to locate package offsec-awae
E: Unable to locate package ohrwurm
E: Unable to locate package ollydbg
E: Unable to locate package oscanner
E: Unable to locate package osrframework
E: Unable to locate package owasp-mantra-ff
E: Unable to locate package owl
E: Unable to locate package pack
E: Unable to locate package pacu
E: Unable to locate package padbuster
E: Unable to locate package paros
E: Unable to locate package passing-the-hash
E: Unable to locate package payloadsallthethings
E: Unable to locate package pdf-parser
E: Unable to locate package pdfid
E: Unable to locate package peirates
E: Unable to locate package perl-cisco-copyconfig
E: Unable to locate package phishery
E: Unable to locate package photon
E: Unable to locate package phishery
E: Unable to locate package phpggc
E: Unable to locate package pipal
E: Unable to locate package plecost
E: Unable to locate package placate
E: Unable to locate package powercat
E: Unable to locate package powershell
E: Unable to locate package powershell-empire
E: Unable to locate package powersploit
E: Unable to locate package protos-sip
E: Unable to locate package pskracker
E: Unable to locate package pwnat
E: Unable to locate package pwncat
E: Unable to locate package faraday
E: Unable to locate package qsslcaudit
E: Unable to locate package quark-engine
E: Unable to locate package libradare2-5.0.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libradare2-5.0.0'
E: Unable to locate package quark-engine
E: Package 'radare2-cutter' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package rainbowcrack
E: Unable to locate package rcracki-mt
E: Unable to locate package rebind
E: Unable to locate package redfang
E: Unable to locate package redsnarf
E: Unable to locate package regripper
E: Unable to locate package responder
E: Unable to locate package rfcat
E: Unable to locate package ridenum
E: Unable to locate package golang-github-temoto-robotstxt-dev
E: Unable to locate package robotstxt
E: Unable to locate package ropper
E: Unable to locate package routerkeygenpc
E: Unable to locate package routersploit
E: Unable to locate package rsmangler
E: Unable to locate package rtlsdr-scanner
E: Unable to locate package rtpbreak
E: Unable to locate package rtpflood
E: Unable to locate package rtpinsertsound
E: Unable to locate package rtpmixsound
E: Unable to locate package sakis3g
E: Unable to locate package sctpscan
E: Unable to locate package seclists
E: Unable to locate package secure-socket-funneling-windows-binaries
E: Unable to locate package set
E: Unable to locate package sfuzz
E: Unable to locate package shellnoob
E: Unable to locate package shellter
E: Unable to locate package sherlock
E: Unable to locate package sidguesser
E: Unable to locate package silenttrinity
E: Unable to locate package siparmyknife
E: Unable to locate package sipp
E: Unable to locate package skipfish
E: Unable to locate package sliver
E: Unable to locate package smali
E: Unable to locate package smtp-user-enum
E: Unable to locate package sniffjoke
E: Unable to locate package snmpcheck
E: Unable to locate package snmpenum
E: Unable to locate package spiderfoot
E: Package 'spike' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package spooftooph
E: Unable to locate package spraykatz
E: Unable to locate package sqldict
E: Unable to locate package sqlninja
E: Unable to locate package sqlsus
E: Unable to locate package sslyze
E: Unable to locate package starkiller
E: Unable to locate package subfinder
E: Unable to locate package subjack
E: Unable to locate package sublist3r
E: Unable to locate package teamsploit
E: Unable to locate package tftpd32
E: Unable to locate package thc-pptp-bruter
E: Unable to locate package thc-ssl-dos
E: Unable to locate package theharvester
E: Unable to locate package tightvncpasswd
E: Unable to locate package tlssled
E: Unable to locate package tnscmd10g
E: Unable to locate package truecrack
E: Unable to locate package tundeep
E: Unable to locate package twofi
E: Package 'u-boot' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package uhd-images
E: Unable to locate package unicornscan
E: Unable to locate package uniscan
E: Unable to locate package unix-privesc-check
E: Unable to locate package urlcrazy
E: Unable to locate package veil
E: Unable to locate package voiphopper
E: Unable to locate package watobo
E: Unable to locate package wce
E: Unable to locate package webacoo
E: Unable to locate package webscarab
E: Unable to locate package webshells
E: Unable to locate package wgetpaste
E: Unable to locate package wifi-honey
E: Unable to locate package wifiphisher
E: Unable to locate package wig-ng
E: Unable to locate package windows-binaries
E: Unable to locate package windows-privesc-check
E: Unable to locate package winexe
E: Unable to locate package libwireshark15
E: Unable to locate package wordlistraider
E: Unable to locate package wordlists
E: Unable to locate package wotmate
E: Unable to locate package wpa-sycophant
E: Unable to locate package wpscan
E: Unable to locate package xplico
E: Unable to locate package xspy
E: Unable to locate package xsser
E: Unable to locate package zaproxy
E: Unable to locate package zenmap-kbx
E: Unable to locate package golang-github-zonedb-zonedb-dev
E: Unable to locate package zonedb
```

Where am I going wrong? Kali is Debian, no? Why can't I install them in Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not a security question, i.e. off-topic. Apart from that Kali and Ubuntu are not Debian but are derivatives of Debian with their own software repositories - some things are shared with stock Debian and others not.

Comment: Set up a Kali machine to install all Kali Tools.  ...... Posted from my Kali machine.

Comment: You might be able to do so by downloading .deb packages.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to download packages (`.deb` files) and using command:

```
gdebi package.deb
```

install them. This command will take care about the dependencies and install them if required.
If they do not exist as `.deb` packages download `snap` and instell them as `snap` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Kali nor Ubuntu "is" Debian. They are just both Debian-based.

You asked your Ubuntu 21.10 system to install the Kali tools without telling it where to get them from. Consequently, it looked for them in the standard Ubuntu repositories, but they aren't there because they are not part of Ubuntu.

You may have more success if you tell your system where it can find the Kali tools, by adding the Kali repositories to your `apt` configuration. Be aware, however, that there may be conflicts between Kali and Ubuntu packages. You may be able to resolve those by careful observation of the messages from `apt`, but it is also possible that you'll damage your system in the attempt.